# PayPalのSandboxのIPN simulatorについて

Tags: paypal

SandboxのInstant Payment Notification (IPN) simulatorについてですが、定期支払いでのテストができない。何か方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

SandboxでのIPNシミュレータですが、定期支払いに固有なフィールドについての送信ができないので、テストは行えませんね。
ただし、Sandbox上で実際のIPNは定期支払いでも送信されるので、テストに色々と時間がかかってもいいなら、実際のIPNで確認することはできると思います。